# c# lock a class but not themselves

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem with understanding multithreading. I will try to explain and hope you will understand what I mean.

I have a class `form1` (inherited from `Form`). This form can be opened several times. When one is opened, a worker thread will start with a global synchronized object which I pass on creating the form.

So every form has the same object to synchronize. This is necessary, because there is a another class which does some work (only one object can be alive). It is not allowed to do this work at the same time.

My problem is the following:

How can I synchronize all threads with the second work class without blocking all threads?

```
// from this form can be exist several objects
public partial class form1 : Form
{
...
    private Object synchronizedObject;
    public void SetSynchronizedObject(Object o)
    {
        synchronizedObject = o;
    }

    // executed threaded
    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (bDoWork)
        {
            try
            {
                bool bLock = Monitor.TryEnter(synchronizedObject);
                if (!bLock)
                {
                    if (bDoWork) 
                    {
                        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            if (panel1 != null)
                                panel1.Visible = true;
                        });
                    }
                    Monitor.Enter(synchronizedObject);

                    if (bDoWork)
                    {
                        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            if (panel1 != null)
                                panel1.Visible = false;
                        });
                    }
                }


                i++;
                if (bDoWork)
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                    {
                        if (textBox != null)
                            textBox.Text = i.ToString();
                    });
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(synchronizedObject);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }            
    }
```

Then there is `form2`. When `form2` does its work, all threads should be blocked. The problem with my code is that `form1` is blocking.

Comment: I am confused. You don't need `lock` to synchronize objects derived from classes (data structures in memory). you need `lock` to synchronize program flows (ie. threads). what do you mean by *synchronize all threads with the second work class*

Comment: rather than trying to explain in words, maybe you should try to explain with code.

Comment: i am sorry, i lock the program flow. i will try to add some code

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're trying to solve can be nicely approached with a "worker". Create a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, add "work" there. Start a worker thread (once)

```
ConcurrentQueue<T> _q;
void Worker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        T element = _q.Dequeue();
        if (element == null)
            break;
        // do work with element here
        // obviously, it will happen one at a time
    }
}
```

*the code in example assumes you don't need the result*

A better approach would be using "Limited concurrency SynchronizationContext", in which case you may use await/async.

Comment: i think, that is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to synchronize your threads by using a shared `synchronizedObject`. That's a good idea, but are you really sure `synchronizedObject`is indeed shared between all the instances? There is a very simple way to really ensure this, without having to use a (potentially buggy) `SetSynchronizedObject` method.

```
    private static readonly Object synchronizedObject = new object();
```

Now you are *sure* `synchronizedObject` is shared between all the instances.

I'm not sure this is the faulty part in your implementation (it depends how you were calling `SetSynchronizedObject`), but it's very easy to ensure there is no potential bug there.

Comment: Yes synchronizedObject is shared in all threads. But this is what i do not want. form2 is blocking form1 but form 1 should not block form1